# How to get Real life Social Network Data?

Tags: dataset, social-network-analysis

I am trying to build a case study for Insurance fraud detection using SNA. I have already looked around and build my model using Stanford's SNAP and other similar databases available on the internet for research. However, I am just wondering, what are the data sources from which I can get Social Network Data apart from the Facebook, Linkedin, Twitter connections.
Can I get (buy) phone call records, or any other social network dataset?
Also, do FB, linkedin sell their connections data?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at these links:

1. https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/1670/any-cdr-call-data-record-dataset
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26229570/dataset-needed-for-cdr-analysis
3. http://vlado.fmf.uni-lj.si/pub/networks/doc/seminar/nicta02.pdf